# How to preload an image and examine its properties before display

Tags: javascript

This is for a carousel side show. I'd like to place the fwd arrow at a fixed location, which would be the location of the widest picture plus an increment. So I'd like to find the width of the widest picture in the array before displaying any of them.

This does not work. What should I do instead? I'm not using JQuery or Angular. Barebones.

I see a previous answer to a similar question, but that will not work for me because it assumes that the number of images is fixed. In my case, they will vary from site to site.

To be included in js.config for every web site:

```
var pictures = ["CodeTalker.jpg", "challenger.jpg", "Hotline.jpg", "EarliestDigraphic.jpg", "Bombe.jpg", "SIGABA.jpg", "SIGCALYSign.jpg", "Cray.jpg"];
var maxWidth = 0;
var image = new Image()
for (picture in pictures) {
    image.src = picture;
    image.loading = "eager";
       if (image.naturalWidth > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = image.naturalWidth;
    }
}

var currentPic = 0;
```

When executed, the natural length always comes back zero.

Comment: The width of an image isn't known until it loads.

Comment: `for...in` loops for object [`for...of` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

###### Hi @Rin,

The issue with your code is the `image.naturalWidth` property is always returning `0`. As Mr.@Dave Newton described in the above comment, The `image` object is not properly being loaded before its properties are being accessed.

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = pictures[i];
    image.onload = function() {
      if (this.naturalWidth > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = this.naturalWidth;
      }
    }
  }
```

`onload` event handler function when image is fully loaded. To ensure that the image is fully loaded before its properties are accessed.

Comment: I think you need to add the images to the document as well ex. `document.body.append(image)`

Comment: Yes, I have written an onload event and found that there is no way of doing what I want to do: contain the picture names in an array, and determine the maximum width before displaying any of them.